# Convert simple codes to html styles

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am making a script for converting some specific tags to known and valid html like

```
[b] bold [/b] for <span style="font-weight:bold"> bold</span>

[color=red] red text [/color] for <span style="font-color:red"> red</span>

[fs=15]big font[/fs] for <span style="font-size:15px"> big font</font>

and [link=http://www.gooole.com target=new title=goole] google[/link] to be converted to

<a href="http://www.gooole.com" title="goole">google</a>
```

and also can mix them like [fs=15] this is big. [color=red] red text[/color] [/fs]

Here is the code that I used-

```
$str = preg_replace( '/\[b\]/', '<span style="font-weight:bold">', $str );
$str =preg_replace( '/\[\/b\]/', '</span>', $str );
$str= preg_replace( '/\[\/fs\]/', '</span>', $str );
$str= preg_replace( '/\[fs=(.*)\]/', '<span style="font-size:$1px">', $str );

$str= preg_replace( '/\[\/color\]/', '</span>', $str );
$str= preg_replace( '/\[color=(.*)\]/', '<span style="font-color:$1">', $str );
```

This code works fine if used not nested and also works in nested if tag don't have = attribute. Problem occurs when I use something like this

```
[fs=15] this is big. [fs=12] this is big.  [/fs] [/fs]
```

It give me

```
<span style="font-size:15] this is big. [fs=12px"> this is big. </span> </span>
```

while it should be

```
<span style="font-size:15px> this is big. <span style="font-size:12px> this is big. </span> </span>
```

Its working fine with

```
[b] hi [i] ok [/i] yes [/b]
```

Please suggest I don't know much regular expression.

Comment: Use non greedy matching: `(.*?)`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Please see my edited question.(your code is working fine thanks but I need one more step!)

Comment: Is it possible to replace all code with just one preg_replace as I used it several times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you always replace the closing tags with `</span>`; include them in a single one.
2. You can use a hash mapping for matching similar tag structures; like `[b]`, `[i]` etc. and use the hashed structure in [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)
3. Use ungreedy (or lazy) matching with possibly ignorecase [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Also, use some other delimiter than `/`.

Try the following code:

```
// first deal with closing tags
$str = preg_replace( '#\[/(color|b|i|fs|so|many|tags|can|go|here)\]#i', '</span>', $str );
// now some functions; with hashmaps
function colsize( $m ) {
    $map = [    // or $map = Array(
        'color' => 'color: %s',
        'fs' => 'size: %dpx'
    ];    // or );
    return sprintf( '<span style="font-' . $map[$m[1]] . ';">', $m[2] );
}
function emph( $m ) {
    $map = [    // or $map = Array(
        'b' => 'weight: bold',
        'i' => 'style: italic'
    ];    // or );
    return '<span style="font-' . $map[$m[1]] . ';">';
}
// using the custom functions from above now
$str = preg_replace_callback( '@\[(color|fs)=([^\]]+)\]@iU', 'colsize', $str );
$str = preg_replace_callback( '@\[([bi])\]@i', 'emph', $str );
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i pass multiple attributes like [link=http://www.google.com target=new] Google [/link]

Comment: @RNKushwaha `$str = preg_replace( '#\[/link=(\S+) target=([^\]]+)\]#i', '<a href="{$1}" target="_{$2}">', $str );`

Answer (score 1):

Use the non-greedy option:

```
$str = preg_replace( '/\[fs=(.*)\]/U', '<span style="font-size:$1px">', $str );
```

And prefer:

```
$str = preg_replace( '/\[fs=(.*)\](.*)\[\/fs\]/U', '<span style="font-size:$1px">$2</span>', $str );
```

Comment: As the message says, a [ is open and not closed so we escape it: `$str = preg_replace( '/\[fs=(.*)\](.*)\[\/fs\]/U', '<span style="font-size:$1px">$2</span>', $str );`